# Navigation in compose with cicirone

Tags: android, navigation, android-jetpack-compose, android-viewmodel

I have router and viewState in viewModel. I have compose view in fragment. Router is a cicirone. I call navigation function from compose and it good work, but if i need navigate after request how i can make it? I emit event in viewState and in compose call navigation, after back navigation i again navigate from viewState. I get looping navigation. I would appreciate any ideas.

```
class ViewModel(
    private val router: Router,
    private val interactor: Interactor,
) : ViewModel() {

   val viewState: StateFlow<ViewState> = interactor.state

   fun someNavigation() {
  }
}
```

```
@Composable
internal fun SomeFun(viewModel: ViewModel) {
    val viewState by viewModel.viewState.collectAsState()

   when(viewState) {
     is SomeState -> viewModel.someNavigation()
   }

}
```